# BucketRandomProjectionLSH KNN parameters

Tags: knn, locality-sensitive-hash

I am trying to use KNN algorithm from spark 2.2.0. I am wondering how I should set my bucket length. The record count/number of features varies, so I think it is better to set length by some conditions. How should I set the bucket length for better performance? I rescaled all the features in vector into 0 to 1.

Also, is there any way to guarantee KNN algorithm to return minimum number of elemnets? I found out that sometimes number of elements inside the bucket is smaller than queried k, and I might want at least one or two neighbors as result.

Thanks~

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSH

Answer (score 2):

According to [Scaladocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel)

> If input vectors are normalized, 1-10 times of `pow(numRecords,
>   -1/inputDim)` would be a reasonable value

Comment: For those who doesn't see this above quoted sentence, try to expand the `Parameters -> val bucketLength`